# how to add tiny-slider to laravel/mix via NPM?

Tags: javascript, npm, laravel-mix, tiny-slider

according to [the official doc](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider), I installed it:

```
npm install tiny-slider
```

then add this to `resources/js/app.js`

```
import { tns } from "./../../node_modules/tiny-slider/src/tiny-slider";
```

also I tried

```
import { tns } from "tiny-slider/src/tiny-slider";
```

them didn't work!

---

By trial and error, I manually add CSS file in `resources/scss/app.scss`

```
@import './../../node_modules/tiny-slider/dist/tiny-slider.css';
```

and in `resources/js/app.js`

```
import { tns } from 'tiny-slider/src/tiny-slider'; 
window.tns = tns;
require('./../../node_modules/tiny-slider/dist/tiny-slider.js');
```

ok, it works. but I think it is unusual.
also, it imported the js file twice.

can somebody please correct my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. In resources/js/app.js

```
import { tns } from "tiny-slider/src/tiny-slider"
window.tns = tns;
```

Then use it as u would.

Comment: Ali knows that `windows.tns=tns` works. Do you have got any idea if there's a better solution?

Comment: I think this is the most suitable solution for webpack, as per the [package documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-slider#install). The line that @Ali is repeating is not necessary. He does not need to import js twice. `(require...)`